# I am having problems with SharedPreferences saving an int

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

```
package com.carterharrison.taptap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    SharedPreferences SP;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SP = getSharedPreferences("points", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    }




        public int x = SP.getInt("points", -1);



    public void val1(View v){

        x = (x+1);
        con();

    }

    public void val2(View v){

        x = (x+2);
        con();
    }

    public void val3(View v){

        x = (x+5);
        con();
        }

    public void val4(View v){

        x = (x+10);
    con();

}

public void val5(View v){

    x = (x+25);
    con();

}

public void val6(View v){

    x = (x+50);
    con();

}

public void con(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor  = SP.edit();

    if (x > 1000) {
        ImageView img5=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        img5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
    if (x > 625) {
        ImageView img4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        img4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
    if (x > 300) {
        ImageView img3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
    if (x > 100) {
        ImageView img2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
    if (x > 30) {
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.val);
    tv.setText("" + x);


    editor.putInt("score", x);
    editor.apply();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**I am trying to save the value of int x. My app crashes on startup, can someone help me, i'm new to this to java and SharedPreferences, thanks. I might be doing it all wrong, I need help saving the value of x.**

Comment: Is there an exception stack trace?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that is.

Comment: If you're using an IDE to run the application, what message gets logged to the console window?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.carterharrison.taptap/com.carterharrison.taptap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: @CarterHarrison where do you have this code. in Activity ?? `getSharedPreferences` needs a context. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: @CarterHarrison have this  `SharedPreferences SP;` before `onCreate`. In `onCreate SP = getSharedPreferences("points", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` in `onCreate`. Context is available once activity is created

Comment: Still getting the error.

Comment: @CarterHarrison i don't think so. post your whole activity code. I don't think you should get the same exception unless some other object is null

Comment: Just updated the code.

Comment: @CarterHarrison 
    `SharedPreferences.Editor editor  = SP.edit();` this is out side onCreate. and looks like outside of any method

Comment: @CarterHarrison and this `public int x = SP.getInt("points", -1);` You can getInt once SP is initialized. It is initialized in onCreate while your code is outside the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set **int** value in **SharedPReference**.

```
public void SaveInt(String key, int value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("points", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

To get **Int** value from **SharedPreference**

```
public void LoadInt(String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("points", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
    int savedValue = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0);
}
```

**Edit:**

Whenever you want to **save** **int** value in **shared preference** just call method
like below:

**SaveInt("my_int", 5);**

Whenever you want to retrieve value of same int:

**int mScore = LoadInt("my_int");**

Hope it will help you.

Comment: But how do i call these functions?

Comment: @CarterHarrison, I have edited my answer, please check.